# how to pass paramter in Route::get in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I m totally new in laravel that's for i face in this problem,

here is my admin controller code

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function index($number){

        echo "Number Passed: $number";  

    }

}
```

here is my route code

```
Route::get('/', [
'as' => 'base-url', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
```

]);

and this says - "Type error: Too few arguments"

How i Pass parameter in this case? help me

Comment: You've tagged multiple versions of Laravel, what one are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Route::get('/{number}', [
    'as' => 'base-url', 
    'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
]);
```

`{number}` would translate to `$number` in your method in the controller which means that if you went to `website.com/123` your method would return `Number Passed: 123`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parameter to be optional you could do:

```
Route::get('/{number?}', [
    'as' => 'base-url', 
    'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
]);
```